# PL/SQL web service deploy

Tags: java, web-services, plsql, glassfish, jdeveloper

I have made an pl/sql web service in Jdeveloper and deployed it to WebLogic server. It works..
Now i need to deploy that WS on Glassfish. I made JDBC connection (ping successful), but allways get an error after try to deploy .war file using Glassfish admin console (localhost:4848)

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : jaxrpc compilation exception. Please see server.log for more details.

Server.log:

```
[2013-12-17T14:42:32.387+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1387287752387] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception while preparing the app : jaxrpc compilation exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: jaxrpc compilation exception
at org.glassfish.webservices.codegen.JaxRpcRICodegen.accept(JaxRpcRICodegen.java:339)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ModuleContentLinker.accept(ModuleContentLinker.java:91)
at org.glassfish.webservices.codegen.JaxRpcRICodegen.accept(JaxRpcRICodegen.java:852)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:621)
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:1958) .....
```

Any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Jdeveloper built your webservice by using proprietary XML descriptor files which are not understood or expected by Glassfish?  Or maybe your webservice expects dependencies which are not satisfied by Glassfish (maybe some .jar files).

I guess what you want is to use the automated code Jdeveloper generates to call your PL/SQL stored procedure.  I suppose your options are:

- Identify and repackage in some way the dependencies you need into the Jdeveloper-generated .ear or .war binary
- Or maybe try to rip off the generated .java or .class you need and repackage it entirely with Apache CXF or some library which understands @WebService annotations.